# VSIX: get/add/remove references

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

How can I list references for a selected project? And add a new reference to a dll on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

1. manipulate the project xml directly or
2. you can use the automation model

The automation model, is the better of the two, the code project article below shows you examples of getting and adding references to a project and the first article shows you how you can use the DTE from outside of Visual Studio itself.

This should give you a head start..

http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005005.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/EnvDTE.aspx